# How do I boost the "shares" score?

Tags: neptunia-v

At the end of chapter's there's a "shares" score. But problematically, there's no more Arfoire/"evil" shares anymore, so shares are basically a zero-sum game. So how does the shares score work? I just got scolded at a chapter end for "only neptune's shares being adequate", so it seems like just spamming Planeptune's shares isn't exactly what you do? Do you try to get shares equal as possible or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a 10 on the share scores you have to get Planeptune shares to 50% anything less than that and you will be scolded for not trying hard enough. I would suggest repeating the Shampuru quest multiple times or any other quest that requires you to hunt monsters.

Comment: Ah, wondered if it was something like that. I really hate this scoring system...I always have a 10 out of 10 for monsters and 0-1 in shares/quests after doing half the quests

Comment: Be sure to get all 40/40 total in a chapter at least once for a trophy and two medals. To get a 10 in quests you must do ALL the quests in that chapter... They are all completable.

Comment: I've been planning to do it on a playthrough 2...I have, without fail, found a quest with an item or enemy I literally can not locate in the unlocked areas in every chapter so far.

Comment: It's not accurate to say all the quests - there are a couple quests given extremely early that cannot be done at all by the time the quest is given, and there's also a couple chapters where you can actually skimp on a quest or three and still get a 10.